# How to generate a square wave by Linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I need to develop a Linux driver that generates a square wave, with a cycle of about 1ms, using the MIPS platform (this is not i386).

I tried some methods, but these are not success:

- Use timer/hrtimer --> but cycle is 12ms and unstable
- Cannot use realtime additional packages as RTLinux/RTAI, because these do not support for MIPS
- Use the kernel-thread with a forever loop and `udelay` function --> It takes too much of the CPU's resource --> Performance is not acceptable

Do you aid me? *Or do you thwart me...?* (Please help!)

Thank you.

Comment: What chip is it? Is there a public datasheet available?

Answer (score 2):

The Unix way would be not doing that at all. Maybe in olden times on single task machines, you would have done like this, but now - if you don't have a hardware circuit that gives to the proper frequency, you may never succeed because hardware timers don't have the necessary resolution, and it may always happen that a task of more importance grabs your CPU time.

Answer (score 1):

As FrankH said, the best solution involves relying on hardware. You should check your processor's reference manual to see if it has a timer.

I'll add this: if it happens to have an Output Compare or PWM subsystem (I'm not familiar with MIPS, but it's not at all uncommon in embedded devices) you can just write a few registers to set it all up, and then you don't need any more processor time.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible, but to get this from within Linux, the hardware must have certain characteristics:

1. you need a programmable timer device that can create an interrupt at sufficiently-high priority that other activity by the Linux kernel (such as scheduling or other interrupts, even) won't preempt / block the interrupt handler, and at sufficient granulatity/frequency to meet your signal stability constraints
2. the "square wave" electrical line must also be programmable and the operation (register write ? memory mapped register write ? special CPU instruction ? ... ?) which switches its state must be guaranteed faster than the shortest cycle time used with the timer above (or else you could get "frequency moire")

If that's the case then your special timer device driver can toggle the line from within its high prio interrupt handler and create the square wave. Since it's both interrupt driven and separate from the normal timer interrupt sources / consumers (i.e. not shared - no latency from possibly dispatching multiple timer events per interrupt), you've got a much better chance of sufficient precision.

Since all this (the existance of a separately-programmable timer device, to start with) is hardware-specific, you need to start with the specs of your CPU/SoC/board and find out if there are multiple independent timers available.